# vue js nested routing setup for navigation bar

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to make my project to have 2 kind of nagigation bar, I have  read some documentation and searching for tutorial on youtube, i did not found anything related to my problem, i want to have 2 kind of nav-bar for each route without refreshing it on every page. I put my nav-bar on app file in the current project, but what i want to do is making another nested routed that displaying another nav-bar and have it own routes, can anyone help me with this problem? simple code example would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `$route.meta` for controlling which navbar to display. This is an easy solution, but you always have to take care of the `nav` (or set a default, like in the snippet below):

```js
const Foo = {
  template: `
    <div>This is Foo</div>
  `
}

const Bar = {
  template: `
    <div>This is Bar</div>
  `
}

const routes = [{
    path: "/",
    redirect: "/foo",
  },
  {
    path: "/foo",
    component: Foo,
    meta: {
      nav: "nav1",
    },
  },
  {
    path: "/bar",
    component: Bar,
    meta: {
      nav: "nav2",
    },
  },
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes,
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: {
    Foo,
    Bar,
  },
  router,
  computed: {
    computedRoute() {
      return this.$route.meta.nav
    },
  },
})
```

```css
.link {
  padding: 0 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-if="computedRoute === 'nav1'">
    <router-link to="/foo" class="link">
      FOO 1
    </router-link>
    <router-link to="/bar" class="link">
      BAR 1
    </router-link>
  </div>
  <div v-else>
    <router-link to="/foo" class="link">
      FOO 2
    </router-link>
    <router-link to="/bar" class="link">
      BAR 2
    </router-link>
  </div>
  <br>
  <hr>
  <router-view />
</div>
```